# What is the BBT (ff) disk partition type?

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, formatting, storage

What is the BBT (ff) disk partition type?

It appears to be the format used on a USB-connected media player.

Where was it created, with what purpose? What are its typical uses? What are it's advantages and its disadvantages?

Where can I find more information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just about any MBR type collection lists partition type 0xFF as “XENIX Bad Block Table” (hence BBT).

This is most certainly not what the media player uses. It’s most likely a proprietary format. You may be able to find information on the net when searching for the specific media player model.